# Is there any pros to not using Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: php, sql, database, many-to-many, relational-database

I have been asked to create a small program for assignment based on given instructions.
I was given two tables I have to create:

`product` table with two fields: `id` and `name`,
`category_of_product` table with two fields: `product_id` and `name`

It is said that product can be in many categories.

I was also given example products:

1. Product: Nike Shoes, Category: Sneakers, Category: New
2. Product: Converse shoes, Category: Trainers, Category: New
   etc.

Every example entry has two categories for purpose of the task and finally I have to make a call to database to get Products that are in `a` category, but are not in `b` category.

First thing that came to my mind was Many-to-Many relation and it still is in my opinion almost the only choice to use. But since I had to I made it this way with duplicate categories where each category can be assigned to only one product.

Finally I have to give pros and cons of the method they gave me and propose alternatives.

The question is: Are there any actual pros to have database set up like that? I thought maybe its a little faster with small amounts of data to query, but I am not sure if this is a good pro for the cons we are getting.

Comment: If a product can have many categories and a category can have many products then it is indeed a M:M relationship. For useful modelling purposes though you would decompose this to two 1:M relationships witha  table that maps products and categories together

Comment: @CaiusJard First Product and second Product I posted are both in Category called `New`.

Comment: oh and both of them are in Category `New` and `Sneakers` or `Trainers`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i stopped at "Category: Sneakers" and "Category: Trainers" and saw them as being in different categories. There are seldom any good reasons to do this (essentially youre saying you plan to have a bit of CSV on each row that lists all the categories a product can be in). It might look like it makes things simpler at the start but it fairly rapidly comes round to bite you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of any "pros" to not defining a relation as it would exist.  If the relation is `product has one to many categories` then it is a many-to-many relationship and we'd be foolish to try and implement it any other way.  Otherwise we cannot guarantee uniqueness, enforce foreign key relations, or create efficient methods for accessing the data.

Comment: Well, I am not going to expand this application to as many fields as you mentioned. Which I belive are all correct. This is a small task I had to do for interview. And I am just wondering what pros are there to not using many-to-many. But seems like You agree with me, that there aren't any... Thanks for detailed answer!